# How to use ternary operator within the jsx of a react component along with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to return null if condition meets and if not render a component using ternary operator in react and typescript.

What I am trying to do?

I have the code like below,

```
{condition1 && condition2 && (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon />
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>
  )}
```

So as seen above if `condition1` and `condition2` is `true` then it renders `firstdiv`.

Now I have to return `null` if `condition3` is `true`.

So in easy if and else something like this,

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    if (condition3) { 
        return null;
    } else {
        return firstdiv;
    }
}
```

So to do that I tried something like below with ternary operator in jsx

```
{conditon1 && condition2 && (
    {condition3 ? return null : (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon/>
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>)
  })}
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct syntax. Could someone help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What does `condition3` evaluate to and why do you need to return `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrapped your ternary into `{}` where it's neither allowed nor necessary.
Also you can't use the `return` statement inside of an expression.

```
{conditon1 && condition2 && (
    condition3 ? null : (
        <firstdiv>
            <seconddiv>
                <Icon/>
            </seconddiv>
        </firstdiv>
    )
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
{conditon1 && condition2 && (
    {!condition3 && (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon/>
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>)
  })}
```

Or even simpler:

```
{
  conditon1 && condition2 && !condition3 && (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon />
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works but it will not return `null` in case `condition3` is `true`.

Comment: Well, it won't return anything if `condition3` is `true`, which has to be considered equivalent to `null`?

Comment: If `condition3` is anything that evaluates to `true` it will return `false` (`!true`) which is not nothing. But as react renders nothing for any element that is `true`, `false`, `null` or `undefined` it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct but fail to explain the reasoning.

1. Within JSX, {} braces must contain a Javascript *expression*

An expression, if you're not familiar with the term, is [any unit of code that can be evaluated to a value is an expression](https://medium.com/launch-school/javascript-expressions-and-statements-4d32ac9c0e74). 
Think anything that gives you can type in REPL and see a value for.

## Why your attempts work or fail

So your first statement form works,

```
{
  condition1 && condition2 && (<p>some JSX<p>)
}
```

This works; it's an expression.

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    if (condition3) { 
        return null;
    } else {
        return firstdiv;
    }
}
```

Doesn't work! Not an expression. You could use this to set a variable at the beginning of your `render()` function and render the variable later, though.

```
{conditon1 && condition2 && (
    {condition3 ? return null : (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon/>
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>)
  })}
```

This is nearly an expression, but not quite. Why is there a `{` beside `condition3`? You are already in Javascript evaluation mode, so this technically starts a code block. But a code block can't be part of an expression, so this is no longer an expression, and so won't work.

## Solutions

## No ternary

You could use the same form without a ternary like this

```
{
  (
    condition1 
    && condition2 
    && !condition3
    && (<p>firstdiv<p>)
  ) || null
}
```

But in fact there's no reason to ever explicitly return null in JSX (why? it won't be rendered), so this can be simplified to:

```
{
  condition1 
  && condition2 
  && !condition3
  && (<p>firstdiv<p>)
}
```

## Ternary

That being said, we can still use ternary for `condition3`.

```
{
  conditon1 
  && condition2 
  && (
    //{ problem was here. You're already in a Javascript context!
    //  { would start a code block here, which you can't do in an expression
    condition3 
    ? return null 
    : (
      <firstdiv>
        <seconddiv>
         <Icon/>
        </seconddiv>
      </firstdiv>
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: *Within Javascript (inside a JSX file), () begin JSX evaluation*. This is not true. `<AnIdentifier` begins jsx evaluation. This is valid: `const aParagraph = <p>foo</p>;`. `()` can wrap any expression and has nothing to do with `jsx`. It can e.g. be used as a [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). You can also do `{condition1 && condition2 && <p>some JSX<p>}` inside of `jsx` without the `()`.

Comment: @trixn this is true

Answer (score 0):

First of all your logic can be more simple like that:

```
if (condition1 && conditions && !condition3) {
 return firstdiv;
} else {
 return null;
}

{conditon1 && condition2 && !condition3 ? <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon/>
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv> : null }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing some `()` to start the JSX context. It might help to also add `render()` and `return` since I think this is how you're picturing it

Answer (score 0):

Place your condition in curly braces since your using JSX, the inside curcly braces, think of you have 3 parameters in your ternary operator, the condition followed by a question mark which stands as the IF is JS, the second and third will be execution if true or false separated by a cologn,
which going to look lile this
{ ( condition1 && condition 2 ) ? firstdiv : null }